# Rasbian Stretch monodevelop does not start anymore

Tags: raspbian-stretch, mono

After the upgrade monodevelop 7.6.0 crashes with unhandled exception. My mono apps which used to work crash as well. They work on other distros with the same mono version.

Any known solution?

Comment: After which upgrade? Any error messages? Pls update your question with these details

Comment: Your development environment is broken. Make a new flash of Raspbian Stretch and reinstall monodevelop.

Comment: @Ingo making a new flash is actually a strange advice. The problem was caused by the mono 5.16 which is just ridiculously unstable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the mono 5.16. Avoid mono 5.16. Downgrade or update to the 5.18 preview version.

5.16 is extremely unstable and I do not understand how they could make it the main stable version. **Avoid**

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.